# Displaying users from the result of a PFCloud callFunction

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

**EDIT:** Solved. I needed to add `[0]` to `resultUser[0][@"firstName"])`. I feel silly.

I have a cloud function that I call in my app, the function does a query and returns any users that meets the query's criteria.

My question is, how can I display the users that I get returned?

Example:

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];

[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"queryWithRange" withParameters:@{@"userId":user.objectId} block:^(PFUser *resultUser, NSError *error)
 {
     if (resultUser)
     {
         NSLog(@"First Name: %@", resultUser[@"firstName"];
     }
 }];
```

The NSLog part returns the error: `[__NSArrayM objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1740571c0`

What am I doing wrong? Cheers.

Comment: It depends on what the cloud function returns.  Try logging just the result to see what you have `NSLog(@"Result is: %@", resultUser);`

Comment: @danh EDIT: I've figured it out